# Application Insights Multi-Step Availability Test Producing 411

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have created a WebTest via Fiddler which POST's to a public endpoint using the basic Authorization method. The call works fine in Fiddler/Postman however when I upload the following webtest as an Azure's Availablity test it fails, giving me a 411 error.

### The Web Test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestCase Name="FiddlerGeneratedWebTest" Id="" Owner="" Description="" Priority="0" Enabled="True" CssProjectStructure="" CssIteration="" DeploymentItemsEditable="" CredentialUserName="" CredentialPassword="" PreAuthenticate="True" Proxy="" RequestCallbackClass="" TestCaseCallbackClass="">
  <Items>
    <Request Method="POST" Version="1.1" Url="https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/mywebjob/run" ThinkTime="0" Timeout="60" ParseDependentRequests="True" FollowRedirects="True" RecordResult="True" Cache="False" ResponseTimeGoal="0" Encoding="utf-8">
      <Headers>
          <Header Name="Authorization" Value="Basic JGRldi1sb2NhbGl0eS13ZWItam9iphYVJSN1o0QjlmUXBNZlhjcXJKSHd1RFpYNW1xWlE4MTNzRnRMMUpOc2JFNXVna3l2aWVhQ3pBNXJvYzg=" />
          <Header Name="Content-Length" Value="0" />
      </Headers>
      <QueryStringParameters>
        <QueryStringParameter Name="arguments" Value="health" UrlEncode="True" UseToGroupResults="False" />
      </QueryStringParameters>
    </Request>
  </Items>
</TestCase>
```

### The Error

Returned once the availability test fails:

```
> 1 primary requests, 0 dependant requests and 0 conditional rules failed
> Http Error (subtype '411 - LengthRequired') occured at 09/06/2018
> 05:49:45 (UTC) for Uri
> 'https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/mywebjob/run?arguments=health',
> step #1 with the error '411 - LengthRequired'.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the web test more than 2 minutes?

Comment: No its a single POST call that returns a 202, takes <100ms in Fiddler/Postman